# selective template html with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, mobile, angular-ui-router

Is it ok to use template html file selectively depending on screen size like this?

```
.state('booklist', {
            url: '/booklist',
            templateUrl: window.innerWidth > 320 ? "largeScreen.html": "mobileScreen.html",
            controller: "TestController"
        })
```

I wanna know this is reasonable way to use template html file for two different screen size and there is pros and cons I didn't figure out.

Thank you.

Comment: Asking whether it's _reasonable_ makes the question rather opinion based and off-topic for SO. I think it would be better to ask whether it's _reliable_ or _maintainable_ etc.

Comment: ok :) maybe it's because english is my second language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is definitely reasonable! This will change the url based on your screen size!

The pros? - it's easy to understand, simple to use and gets the job done.

The cons? - it doesn't change if you resize the screen like you would on a desktop/laptop but you may not care about that.  This is definitely something that represents an extreme minor case, but if you're a perfectionist then it certainly is a con!

As peter has commented, you should certainly consider using media queries rather than using different templates, however there may be some cases where you want the smaller screens to show something completely different (e.g you may want accordions) in which case is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Is that 'ok'? It's a solution, but a pretty hacky one. You should really use responsive web frameworks like Zurb Foundation, or Twitter Bootstrap that do this for you in style, and not in program logic.

I would make the call based on how serious this project is and how big it's going to get. You will have headaches at the very least with:

- styling, because you've now mixed styling into the logic of your program and will need to remember that every time you make a layout related style decision
- unit testing, because every time you run a unit test you will need to remember to manually fix the window size to make sure the right template loads

These don't sound major but forgetting about your hacky workaround down the line could waste hours of your time, and it's plain bad practice.

You should be solving style-related problems with CSS.

Comment: It doesn't look like an answer.

Comment: then you didn't read the question, because he asked if it was reasonable (I answered) and what the pros and cons were (which I provided)

Comment: ok, my bad... I admit I missed one or two words... sorry ;-)

Comment: The question is for SO off-topic anyway... it's option based so it should have been asked on Code Review or differently like whether it's a reliable solution.

Comment: Ok noted, i'm new :)